Property Online Manual Reference
I'm looking for a way to add online manual references to properties in a property group. I've found the method for operators in the 'Addon Add Object' Python template, but unfortunately, I couldn't find a way for properties, either in a template or elsewhere.
def add_object_manual_map():
    url_manual_prefix = "https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/"
    url_manual_mapping = (
        ("bpy.ops.mesh.add_object", "scene_layout/object/types.html"),
    )
    return url_manual_prefix, url_manual_mapping

bpy.utils.register_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)


It turns out that the solution is simply to extend the mapping of the operators with the property’s reference, such as: bpy.types.RenderSettings.filepath.
However, when I referenced my own property, it didn’t work. The solution for this was to lowercase the reference, like: bpy.types.rendersettings.filepath.
This solution was suggested by Blender’s console when opening the online manual for a default Blender property, which printed:

Online manual check for: 'bpy.types.RenderSettings.filepath'...
Match found: 'bpy.types.rendersettings.filepath*' --> 'render/output/properties/output.html#bpy-types-rendersettings-filepath'

The use of lowercase is also mentioned in the code of the online manual operator.
So, the original code template for the operator's online manual reference, extended with the property would look like this:
def add_object_manual_map():
    url_manual_prefix = "https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/"
    url_manual_mapping = (
        ("bpy.ops.mesh.add_object", "scene_layout/object/types.html"),
        ("bpy.types.rendersettings.filepath", "render/output/properties/output.html#bpy-types-rendersettings-filepath"),
    )
    return url_manual_prefix, url_manual_mapping

bpy.utils.register_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)

